# #default_value for select form elements does not work

Tags: forms

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\dishes_dropdown\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;

/**
 * Desarrollo de un formulario en drupal 8
 *
 */
class DishesDropdownForm extends FormBase {


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'dishes_dropdown_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $maxlength = 250;

        $tax_terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('dish_type', $parent=0, $max_depth=NULL, $load_entities=FALSE);
        $taxs = array();
        foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
            $taxs[$tax_term->tid] = $tax_term->name;
        }

        $form['dish_dropdown'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#options' => $taxs,
            '#chosen' => true,
            '#multiple' => false,
            '#maxlength' => $maxlength,
            '#default_value' => $form_state->hasValue('dish_dropdown') ? $form_state->getValue('dish_dropdown') : '' ,

        $form['submit'] = [
            '#type'  => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Ir al tipo de plato'),
            '#weight' => 50,
        ];
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        // Display result.
        $id = reset($form_state-> getValues('dish_dropdown'));
        $aliasManager = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager');
        // The second argument to getAliasByPath is a language code such as "en" or LanguageInterface::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE.
        $alias = $aliasManager->getAliasByPath('/taxonomy/term/' . $id);

        $url = new TrustedRedirectResponse($alias);
        if (isset($url)) {
            $form_state-> setResponse($url);
        }

        return;


    }
}
```

---

I do not load the "default_value" in select. I have tried a thousand ways in the "build" but there is no way. I want a blank default value but without forcing it load it. It's like if you read the "default_value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **#default_value** for a select element should be an integer value matching an array **key** in the **#options** array.

In your case, lets say

```
$taxs = [5 => 'blue dish', 9 => 'red dish', 15 => 'green dish'];
```

Then an option for the value for *#default_value will be one of 5,9 or 15.

In your case the function *$form_state->hasValue('dish_dropdown')* will return one of "blue dish", "red dish" or "green dish" which is **not** an array key in your $taxs array.

So what do you do?

1. Either select one of your dish types as the default **OR**
2. Add a default value *- None -*

For example:

```
$taxs[0] = '-- None --';
$reverseTaxs = array_flip($taxs);
$form['dish_dropdown'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $taxs,
        '#chosen' => true,
        '#multiple' => false,
        '#maxlength' => $maxlength,
        '#default_value' => $form_state->hasValue('dish_dropdown') ? $reverseTaxs[$form_state->getValue('dish_dropdown')] : 0 ,

    $form['submit'] = [
        '#type'  => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Ir al tipo de plato'),
        '#weight' => 50,
    ];
    return $form;
```